# Does self-phase modulation (SPM) depend on Raman scattering?

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics

SPM and Raman scattering both cause spectral (frequency domain) broadening of ultrashort laser pulses. So I was wondering if what we know as SPM spectral broadening is dependent on Raman scattering at microscopic level. SPM is a nonlinear process. What about Raman scattering? If Raman is not nonlinear, then can a nonlinear process be dependent on a linear process?

Comment: SPM is a parametric process, meaning that it leaves the medium unchanged. In contrast, Raman scattering is an inelastic scattering process where energy is deposited into or extracted from the medium. Therefore the two are different on a microscopic level.

Comment: @fulis I recommend you basically post your comment as an answer. It fully satisfies the question, not only as a comment.

Comment: @fulis, so what is responsible for SPM at the quantum mechanical (microscopic) level?

Comment: Oh, because I was not tagged, I now see that you did not have another answer. To answer you, the an-harmonicity of the valence band is what creates nonlinear parametric signals. For linear transmission you approximate the valence band as a quadratic well. However under strong fields you "explore" more of the valence band and the (non-harmonic) curve of the well forces the creation of new frequencies. Raman scattering comes from energy levels, not the electron movement in their potential wells.

Comment: see this answer i gave: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665600/physical-origin-of-kerr-effect/666187#666187